# React history push not rendering the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am new to the `react js`. I am using the following way for the purpose of the react route,

In the main component

```
render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                        <Switch>
                            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={ LandingScreen } />
                            <PrivateRoute exact path="/QuizSetupMain" component={QuizSetupMain} />
                            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>


        )
```

privateRoute ->

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Loading from '../Loader/Loading';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, hasUserLogIn, ...rest }) => {
    return <Route
        {...rest}
        render={
            props => {
                return hasUserLogIn ?
                (
                    isFetching ? <Loading /> :  
                    <Component {...props} />
                )
                :
                (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/login",
                            state: { from: props.location }
                        }}
                    />
                )
            }
        }
    />
};


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        hasUserLogIn: state.LoginReducer.hasUserLogIn,
        isFetching: state.LoginReducer.isFetching
    }
}
```

Here 
   after success of login,

```
case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            console.log("going in LOGIN_SUCCESS");
            return {
                ...state,
                hasUserLogIn: true,
                response: action.data,
                error: false,
                isFetching: true,
                loginRequest: false
            }
```

this state will return, so here if you see `isFetching` is a property that I am using the `privateRoutes.js` , then also it does not call that loader .

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PrivateRoute);
```

So, here What I want to do is that, when a user is not logged in the redirected user to the login page. after that, it should be redirected to the `/` home page. so, I am doing that from,

```
export function sendUserJd(data, dispatch) {
    dispatch(setFlag());
    history.push('/');
    return {
        type: FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS,
        data: data,
    }
}
```

So, but still, it is not rendering the landing screen and also not going in the private route after login. can any one tell me why is this happening? Thanks.

Comment: You are using BrowserRouter, but a custom history object which doesn't synchronise well together

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `custom history object` in the action to change `Route`, you need to use a Router with a custom `history` object that you use in the action creator.

```
import { history } from 'path/to/history';

<Router history={history}>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={ LandingScreen } />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/QuizSetupMain" component={QuizSetupMain} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
```

As per the loading condition, you would write it like

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isFetching, hasUserLogIn, path, ...rest }) => {
    if(isFetching){
         return  <Loading /> 
    }
    return hasUserLogIn ?
                (
                    <Route
                       {...rest}
                       path={path}
                       component={Component}   
                     />
                )
                :
                (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/login",
                            state: { from: path }
                        }}
                    />
                )
};
```

Comment: Do u want me to change the browserRouter to router?

Comment: @ganesh, BrowserRouter to Route and pass in the history object that you use in action creator

Comment: thanks a lot I changed that to router and its working, but one thing is I have changed my code a bit so that I can add a loader over there so  . weather it is right or wrong ?

Comment: Where do you add a loader, I didn't get you

Comment: And one thing, after login response for some fraction of seconds also the I see login page and the i get redirected to the / route. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: isFetching ? <Loading /> :    this line in the private route

Comment: It seems that `isFetching ? <Loading /> : ` must be before the `hasLoggedIn` check. Not sure about the wait time before route change

Comment: I tried that but its giving me some errors, can u suggest a bit in the answer ? Just a request.

Comment: Updated my answer, but ofcourse, you need to pass the isFetching value to the PrivateRoute as props

Comment: you have used props.location, but its undefined now .

Comment: is there any specific reason why the mapStateToProps does not get called after the state updation ?

Comment: I am not sure how to help with that, looking at the above code

Comment: Did you check my updated code, because isFetching is not defined in your PrivateRoute component

Comment: I have just added that.

Comment: Actually I was doing a wrong thing.  I was not calling the  /  route on the success of the Login, I was calling another api immediately and on success of that I was calling the / . so, because of that after login success as well it was not changing the route to  / so because of that PrivateRoute will not get called. And so may be it was not showing that loader. This is my understanding.